# How many units does the hidden layer have?

Tags: neural-network, pybrain, fann

I'm getting started in artificial neural networks programming. I would like to know if there is some sort of calculation to determine the exact number of units a hidden layer in a feedforward multilayer network should have according to the number of the inputs and outputs it has. For example, in the classic XOR function, there are 2 inputs and 1 output. How do I know the hidden layer might have 3 units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking:

more linear problem => less hidden nodes, more non-linear => more hidden nodes.

more generalisation => less hidden nodes, less generalisation => more hidden nodes

accurate answer (at least for your training set) => more hidden nodes, approximate answer => less hidden nodes

FYI: in the case of xor, if both inputs are connected straight to the output then a single additional hidden node is required. If no input to output connections are allowed then two hidden nodes will be the minimum.

In answer to the question is there a formula giving the exact number of hidden nodes for problems in general - no.

Comment: What is generalisation exactly?

Comment: Generalization: "The ability to classify future data instance correctly or at least as correct as it was reported to be after training". In other words: generalization is important if you want to classify never-seen-before data instances by the network.

Answer (score 1):

## No

The short, but correct, answer is that there isn't any definition of "the right amount" of hidden nodes in a layer. There are a few guide lines though, such as not using more hidden nodes in a given layer than there are input singals.

**Configuring your network**

The bottom line is that you have to calibrate the number of hidden nodes according to your particular dataset or problem instance. It is important to remeber that using as few hidden nodes as possible is favorable as this will ensure the network is generalized.

Comment: Why is it important to use as few hidden nodes as possible? I didn't understand.

Comment: Lets say you knew that you only needed 6 hidden nodes to accurately (enough) describe your training set. Then by adding extra nodes, the network will teach itself (accidental) dependencies between the input values. These self-taught and erroneous patterns will lower the overall accuracy of your neural network as you apply new instances of input signals - since these patterns doesnt really exist.